# Software for distributing algorithms and flowcharts

Tags: iphone-app, google-apps, workflow, distributed, flowchart

I am looking for software that I can use to distribute instructions to other users in the
form of algorithms or flowcharts.

### Absolute requirements:

- The app runs on either Android OR Apple devices
- Users see the contents of the instructions in the app
- Users can search the instructions
- Only selected users should be able to see the instructions
- Only I am allowed to change the contents

### Nice to have:

- The app runs on BOTH Android AND Apple devices
- The instructions should be available offline and synchronize regularly
- The instructions should be linked to each other via cross-references (see example below)
- The instructions should be attractively designed (e.g. the user should be able to click through)

### An (ridiculously unrealistic) example:

- I am publishing instructions for baking a cake
- A user follows these instructions:

  - "Baking a cake" Step 1: You will need 150g flour (refer to the "Making flour" instructions)

    - "Making flour" Step 1: Harvest 1kg wheat
    - "Making flour" Step 2: etc...
  - "Baking a cake" Step 2: You will need 3 eggs (refer to the "Gathering eggs" instructions)
  - etc...
  - "Baking a cake" Step n: Is the cake golden brown? (decision yes/no)

    - Yes: Take out the cake (refer to "How to take cake out of the oven" instructions)
    - No: Freak out (refer to "How to freak out" instructions)
- I want to change the instructions because obviously you need 2kg of wheat instead of just 1kg for making 150g of flour
- Next time the user will be shown the new instructions